# Change the Default Fav icon in cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How to change the title logo in cakephp 3.0 ? Added another image instead of default cakephp logo image Anyone explain with example

Thank you

Comment: could you please post your work done?

Comment: Title logo? You mean Favicon? Please be a little more specific, and as @loganSarav already said, explain what exactly you've tried so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fav icon can be edited by using the below code layout file.

```
$this->Html->meta(
    'favicon.ico',
    '/favicon.ico',
    ['type' => 'icon']
);
```

replace the favicon.ico with image you want.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Why declare "favicno.ico" twice?

Comment: @Daniel Faria <?= $this->Html->meta(
    'favicon.ico',// image name
    '/favicon.ico',// image path
    ['type' => 'icon']// type
);
?>